# Read Line after specific line

Tags: c#, streamreader

I'm trying to do so that I can read all the lines that are present after the "check", I tried with StreamReader or clicli while and for, without being able to move to the next line, the same line is always read.

below is an example .txt file extracted, in the file there are many registry keys.

TXTFile

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00


//BEFORE MORE key

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Thingamahoochie\WinMerge\Settings-Bar1]
"BarID"=dword:00008033
"Visible"=dword:00000000
"XPos"=dword:fffffffe
"YPos"=dword:fffffffe
"Docking"=dword:00000001
"MRUDockID"=dword:00000000
"MRUDockLeftPos"=dword:00000000
"MRUDockTopPos"=dword:00000000
"MRUDockRightPos"=dword:0000070c
"MRUDockBottomPos"=dword:000000f5
"MRUFloatStyle"=dword:00002004
"MRUFloatXPos"=dword:80000000
"MRUFloatYPos"=dword:00000000

//MORE KEY AFTER
```

code

```
private void btnReplace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     string check = "[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Thingamahoochie\WinMerge\Settings-Bar1]";

     foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(_path))
     {
         if(line == check)
         {
            //need here read all line after "check"

         }
    }
}
```

Comment: For one thing, you need to escape your backslashes in the string literal, or flag the string as raw.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a boolean to keep track of whether you're in the right place:

Here I'm assuming that a blank line indicates the end of the section.

```
bool readingTargetSection = false;
foreach (string line in File.ReadLines(_path))  
{
    if (readingTargetSection)
    {
        if (line.Trim() == "") {
            // or just break out of the loop
            readingTargetSection = false;
        }
        else {
            // read the line
        }
    }       
    else if (line == check)
    {
        readingTargetSection = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for the support, the problem is that now he reads all the lines after the "check", would that crash occurs just find an empty line, I tried to insert:

     if ((readingTargetSection) && (line != "\""))

but not work

Comment: Of course, `readingTargetSection` must be reset after every line which is *not* `check`. Like `readingTargetSection = (line == check)`.

Comment: You did say *//need here read all line after "check"* in the question. If you want to stop reading on a blank line, see my edit.

Answer (score 1):

LINQ can be used here.

```
private void btnReplace_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // The '@' marks the string as a verbatim string.
    string check = @"[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Thingamahoochie\WinMerge\Settings-Bar1]";

    var linesAfterCheck = File.ReadLines(_path)
    .SkipWhile(l => l != check) // Skip until check
    .Skip(1); // Skip line containing check

    foreach (string line in linesAfterCheck)  
    {
        // Code
    }
}
```